# Recoding volume very low when using RHA MA750i headset with Microsoft's Surface Book

Tags: windows-10, audio, skype, headphones, microsoft-surface

I have an [RHA MA750i headset](http://www.rha-audio.com/ie/headphones/ma750i.html) which work perfectly as a headset with my Android phone, and to listen to music on my Core i7 Surface Book. However, when using them with Skype or Skype for Business on my Surface Book, the Microphone volume is considerably lower than it is if I make the call with the same people on the same service from my Android phone.

To try and diagnose this issue I have checked the sound settings in Windows 10 and ensured that `Headset Microphone` is selected as the default device in the "Recording Settings" and that the levels remain configured at their maximum in the properties of the recording device.  Also, I have gone into Skype settings and checked that `Headset Microphone` is set as the default Microphone and again the levels are at their maximum.

Using the Skype Echo Service I have tested the volume of the recorded sounds and while audible through the Headset Microphone it is not at a high enough volume to be usable in a Skype conversation.  If however I make the same call from my phone the call is clear and crisp. Equally, if I use a [Jabra ENC010](http://www.jabra.com/products/accessories/jabra_evolve_accessories/jabra_evolve_link_uc) with [Jabra Evolve Headset](http://www.jabra.com/business/office-headsets/jabra-evolve) on my Surface Book, then the sound is exceptionally clear.